# Is there a CSS flexbox equivalent to CSS grid with grid-template-columns: max-content auto;

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have some CSS using the `grid` layout mechanism. I need to reproduce it using flexbox if possible. The reasons aren't important, so please don't ask. If I could use grid, I would, believe me.

Here is the snippet:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}

<div class="container">
  <div>Heading 123</div>
  <div>Body 123</div>
  <div>Heading ABCDEF</div>
  <div>Body ABCDEF</div>
</div>
```

Specifically I need the columns on the left to have their width be the largest item, and the columns on the right to have there row heights grow.

I have tried using flexbox, but I could not solve it myself

Comment: *The reasons aren't important, so please don't ask* --> They **are** important because the question should be useful to the community not only you.

Comment: Okay. The reasons are that I have some self imposed constraints that I am not flexible on.

Comment: Valid reasons might possibly be to target outdated browsers that don't support grid (or only support -ms-grid Syntax) so that the layout does not look broken on older devices.

Comment: Ah my bad. Thats the reason yeah

Comment: Are there constraints on the markup?  Must it stay the same?

Comment: Hey @jme11 No. The markup can stay the same. The css can change. It just must use flexbox